# "lightning locker" in B2b commerce template does not turn on

Tags: lightning-components, b2b-commerce, lightning-locker

"lightning locker" in B2b commerce template does not turn on, how can I switch to on?

after activating it recharges and goes back to off
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightning Locker is turned off by default in the B2B or B2C LWR template. This is by design and not a bug.

Lightning Web Security (LWS) is the replacement for Lightning Locker ([reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_intro#:%7E:text=for%20Lightning%20components.-,LWS%20started%20to%20replace%20Lightning%20Locker%20for%20Lightning%20web%20components%20initially%20in%20Spring%20%E2%80%9922.,-The%20Lightning%20Component)). As of the Winter ‘23 release, new orgs have LWS for LWC enabled by default. That's the reason Salesforce has disabled Lightning Locker for B2B/B2C LWR templates in general.
See Reference Docs [1](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000392327&type=1#:%7E:text=We%20announced%20in%20the%C2%A0Winter%20%E2%80%9923%20release%20notes%20that%20LWS%20for%20Lightning%20web%20components%20is%20enabled%20by%20default%20in%20new%20Salesforce%20orgs.) , [2](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/12/what-isv-partners-need-to-know-about-lightning-web-security)

Salesforce Product team has filed a documentation bug #W-12536963 for documentation to reflect this and there is no ETA on the fix yet.

For third-party Lightning web components, managed package developers must configure the lightningCommunity__RelaxedCSP value in the capability tag of the [component’s configuration file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags).

Comment: It didn't work, the components are still disabled with lightningCommunity__RelaxedCSP

Comment: Do you see any error? As per [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_security_locker_off_components.htm?q=locker) it should be possible